# how should I use the variable I'm watching inside the angularjs $watch() function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I have been learning how to use directives in angularjs to include jQuery plugins using the tutorials [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs) and [here](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/11/angular-js-directive-basics.html). I am trying to incorporate [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) and I have successfully gotten the calendar initialized and displaying, but now I'm a little stuck. I am currently getting my data from a json file ( eventually will come from a factory and php get response) but I am unsure how I should reference the json data in my directive and need some guidance.

currently I have the below, but **what would be the correct/best approach** to not hard coding and keeping it flexible. I know I could possibly put a `$http.get()` request within the directive but I feel that I shouldn't be making any requests from with my directive ( unless some one can convince me that this approach isn't bad practice)

this is my current directive.js ( please not getJSON() is only for testing)

```
   angular.module('Directives', [])
     .directive('mycalendar', function () {
     getJSON = function () {
         return [{
             "title": "Fitness",
             "start": "2013-08-01 06:30:00",
             "instructor": "3"
         }]
     }

     var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
         scope.$watch('classesList', function () {
             /**/
             element.fullCalendar({
                 header: {
                     left: 'prev,next today',
                     center: 'title',
                     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                 },
                 editable: true,
                 events: getJSON()
                 /**/
             });
         });
     }
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: linker
     }
 });
```

my controller:

```
angular.module('Controllers', [])
    .controller('CalController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'json/classes.json';
    $scope.classesList = [];

    $scope.fetchClasses = function () {
        $http.get($scope.url)
            .then(function (result) {
            $scope.classesList = result.data;
        });
        $scope.fetchClasses();
    }
});
```

my HTML:

```
  <div id="container" ng-controller="CalController">
    <div id='calendar' mycalendar></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same full calendar is available as Module @ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

Please look at it

Or

Check the below URL

http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/xqjtw/59/

Check the controller part of above url:

```
 $scope.eventSource = {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
        };
```

Here "$scope.eventSource" is static you can make it dynamic by Create service function and use $http and inject service function in your controller

below is the example for the same :

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
   return {
     getList:function(params){
          var promise= $http({url: 'ServerURL',method: "POST", params: params}).then(function(response,status){

            return response.data;
            });
          // Return the promise to the controller
          return promise; 
        }
   }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.getList(function(data) {
    $scope.eventSource = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the pointer to the angular version of fullCalendar but I was more looking for how to adapt mine to work, but the ngModel in your jsFiddle has given me something to look at, thank you